# Laravel file manager Multiply Users

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I need Laravel file manager, but by default i need 'allow_multi_user' => false, and only allowed in admin panel.

How to do that? 
tried to do:

```
        $('#lfm').filemanager('image',{allow_multi_user: true});
```

but lfm do not create new folders

Comment: users will be allow to upload files (user->id in folder images{id}) , but if admin will upload some files to their posts - this files will goes in admins`foldes. Its bad.   i need 2 configurations, but how?

Comment: i can`t do that, becouse i have another features which will brokes on  allow_multi_user: true

Comment: Tried setting `'allow_share_folder' => true,` in the configuration?

Comment: allow_share_folder works only if allow_multi_user is true